# Web api error when a string value is null

Tags: c#, oracle, rest, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

This is the error that i got when i try to pass one of the values "in blank" / null . The strange is the fact that just one parameter cause this problem... just the "nomePai"
And on the database, the storedprocedure is ok...

If i pass NomeEnvolvido=Teste , nomeMae=Teste , nomePai=Teste , Dtnasc=01/01/2000 -> OKKKKK

If i pass NomeEnvolvido=Teste , nomeMae= , nomePai=Teste , Dtnasc=01/01/2000 -> OKKKKK

**BUT** If i pass NomeEnvolvido=Teste , nomeMae=Teste , nomePai= ,  Dtnasc=01/01/2000 , i got the error:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent'1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":null,"InnerException":{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Objeto não pode ser convertido de DBNull em outros tipos.","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidCastException","StackTrace":"   em System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)\r\n   em System.Convert.ToDateTime(Object value)\r\n   em WebApiApp.Controllers.NomesController.<>c.b__1_0(DataRow row) na C:\Users\50216740\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\AppMobilePCRJ\AppMobilePCRJ\WebApiApp\Controllers\NomesController.cs:linha 69\r\n   em System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   em System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   em System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   em System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   em System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\r\n   em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   em System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__1b.MoveNext()"}}

[controller code]

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("Envolvidos")]
        public IEnumerable<Envolvido> GetEnvolv(string nomePesquisa, string nomeMae, string nomePai,  Nullable<DateTime> dtnasc
            , string nRG, string nCPF)
        {

            DataSet lretorno = new DataSet();

            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                OracleDataReader reader = null;
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd = new OracleCommand("MOBILE.XAPIMANDADOMOBILE.BUSCAPOSSIVEISCANDIDATOSPF", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //variáveis entrada            
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivnome",nomePesquisa));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivmae", nomeMae));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivpai", nomePai));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivdatanasc", dtnasc));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivrg", nRG));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("icpf", nCPF));
                //variáveis de saida          
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("oretorno", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("qretorno", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                //CRIO A LISTA
                lretorno.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "BUSCAPOSSIVEISCANDIDATOSPF");
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();

                //CARREGO O DATASET E TRANSFORMO PARA IENUMERABLE E RETORNO SEUS VALORES PRO JSON
                return lretorno.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Envolvido
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["SUSPID"]),
                    IVNOME = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPNOME"]),
                    IVMAE = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPMAE"]),
                    IVPAI = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPPAI"]),
                    IVDATANASC = Convert.ToDateTime(row["SUSPDATANASC"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                    IVRG = Convert.ToString(row["RG"]),
                    ICPF = Convert.ToString(row["CPF"]),
                    MANDADO = Convert.ToInt16(row["TEMMANDADO"]),
                    OCORRENCIA = Convert.ToInt16(row["TEMOCORRENCIA"]),

                });

            }
        }
```

[Class Envolvido]

```
namespace WebApiApp.Models
{
    public class Envolvido
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 ID { get; set; }
        public string IVNOME { get; set; }
        public string IVMAE { get; set; }
        public string IVPAI { get; set; }
        public string IVDATANASC { get; set; }
        public string IVRG { get; set; }
        public string ICPF { get; set; }
        public Int16 MANDADO { get; set; }
        public Int16 OCORRENCIA { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Regards...

Comment: Based on the stack trace `Convert.ToDateTime(row["SUSPDATANASC"])` is probably the problem. Whatever `row["SUSPDATANASC"]` returns it cannot be converted to a `DateTime` instance.

Comment: @Igor but when i put a datetime value, i don´t have the error ! And if i put a nomePai value and leave datetime null, i don´t have the error too!

Comment: i got !! i changed to just (row["SUSPDATANASC"]).tostring() and used <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />